# Check remote file existence on multiple Windows servers

Tags: batch-file, windows-authentication, unc, windows-scripting

I need to check a file status (existing? or last modified date) on multiple remote Windows servers (in LAN). The files are accessible via UNC path. The remote PCs need a user name and password. It's best to be some sort of script.

I am not system admin, but asked to do this by my boss because each of these PCs are host of SQL Server and the file is a backup of database. I am a SQL Server database developer. I was trying to do it using T-SQL, but just found it not geared to do this (although maybe doable).

Comment: Are the files on those Windows servers accessible via some shared folder? I.e. do you have an UNC path to access them? Or do you need to use some file transfer protocol (FTP, or whatever)?

Comment: yes, they are accessible via UNC path.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Please include this infomation to your question, to make it more clear and useful for other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file like (say `check.bat`):

```
@echo off

set list=server1 server2 server3 server4 serverN

for %%s in (%list%) do (
    echo Logging in to %%s
    net use \\%%s\shared /user:mydomain\myuser password    

    echo Checking file existence on %%s
    if exist \\%%s\shared\file.txt (
        echo File exist on %%s
    ) else (
        echo File does NOT exist on %%s
    )

    echo Logging out
    net use \\%%s\shared /delete
)
```

For details on the `net use` commands, see the accepted answer for question [Mapping a network drive without hardcoding a drive letter in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3716422/850848).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. is myuser the username, and password the password ? And you mean save this to a .cmd file then run? The screen disappeared immediately after run, so how can I know the result? I am really rookie on this

Comment: Username/password: Yes. Save to .cmd: Yes. Disapearing: You can put `pause` command at the end. But you probably want to do do some action, when file exists or not (instead of `echo File exists`). You have not specified this. Please, accept the answer, if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: I need it to loop through all remote servers so that I can get a list of some kind of which server has the file or not.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how to re-use the batch for many servers.

Comment: do you have some kind of script for the looping? There are more than one hundred servers. I really think there should be some way to do a looping of some kind? Can you tell me where I can find the reference to this (not sure the name) windows scripting? I will mark it as answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use looping. But you need to have a list of servers somewhere anyway. Or are the server numbered?