# Copying a file using a batch file from a RemoteDesktop using the static ip username and password

Tags: batch-file, remote-desktop

I would like to create a bat. file on my computer who is connected to another computer using nothing but a switch, there is no server.
the remote desktop has a static ip a username and a password which are known to me.

I saw and used this code in the bat. file on my computer:

```
net use "\172.17.0.27" typePassword /user:domain\typeUsername
XCOPY "\172.17.0.27\C$\Reports\" "C:\Trades_Backup" /y /d
```

it did not work did not copy any files

Comment: Were you to follow the usage information, visible by entering `net use /?` at the Command Prompt, you'd note that there's something missing from your command line: `NET USE [devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename] [password] [/USER:domainname\username]`!

Comment: With the `NET USE` command you need to specify the share as well. In this case it is the administrative share of the C: drive on the remote computer.  So add the `C$` to the net use command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping a network drive without hardcoding a drive letter in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716422/mapping-a-network-drive-without-hardcoding-a-drive-letter-in-a-batch-file)