# How can I read a file from a remote computer?

Tags: file, vbscript, remote-server

I have a VBScript where I am parsing out information from windowsupdate.log. I had it working locally just fine and when connecting to a server on the same domain as me.

I changed the way I am connecting to servers, I am doing

```
Set locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objWmiService = locator.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2",strUsername,strPassword)
objWmiService.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3
```

Now, the code that was working is

```
strFilePath = "\\" & strComputer & "\c$\Windows\windowsupdate.log"
set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
   strLine = objFile.ReadLine()
   'Logic to parse line
    ...
loop
```

But as I said, it only works for localhost or a server on the same domain.

Is there a different way I can get a file, either I'm not searching correctly or it doesn't exist but I can't find a different way.

Comment: Are you administrator to this computers? Do you have direct network access to them?

Comment: I have provisioned a temporary Administrator account for the domain that the server is on. Right now we are just prototyping capabilities but the username, password that I pass into the script will have admin rights to each computer it connects to. I can RDP into it using the credentials. At the moment, I am just using this one test server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631401/access-network-share-from-within-vbscript-eg-filesystemobject) post - by creating a temporary network share.

Works well!