# Excel VBA to get UNC from cell and open it in explorer.exe

Tags: windows, vba, excel, ms-office

I have a file with a list of PC hostnames I want to be able to connect to the C drive of a specific one by clicking in a cell or button or something.

Let's say I currently have the hostname in Column A. I use CONCATENATE to turn it into a proper network path \\hostname\C$ and put that in Column B.

Now how can I make it so I can just click on the cell in column B to open that location in explorer.exe?
I have 450 PCs so i need to be able to specify the range, feed the network path into VBA and then open that in explorer.exe
does this make any sense? :P

Would really, really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the concatenated value in a "Hyperlink()". From then on it is clickable and it will open the explorer.

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("\\";A1;"\C$");A1)
```

Or you put this code in your Worksheet code pane and double click the cells, where your links stand. But then you mustnt use it in combination with HYPERLINK.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub
Dim sh As Object
Set sh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sh.Run ("explorer " & Target.Value)
Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, I did this and it just says "cannot open the specified file". I know the link is OK because I can paste it in Start > Run and it will connect fine. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: so how does your link look like, without the friendlyname property?

Comment: OK I figured out that it wasn't working because I usually need to enter an admin password when connecting to a network PC (for the current Windows session, I guess). Once I connect via Start > Run and enter the username/password, I can then connect to it from the Excel file, but not before I do that. Is there a way to work around this or is there just no way of doing what I want? I tried running Excel as admin but not working (I actually need to Run as Another user and enter my domain admin password)

Comment: i found this, maybe I can try working this into my spreadsheet. I think i'll definitely need to use some VBA for what I want, instead of just formulas (if it's even possible, that is) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248221/access-shared-network-folder

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but your second piece of code doesn't seem to do anything. When I double click in a cell, it just tries to edit the formula, and if I disable the in-cell editing, nothing happens. Maybe I missed something? Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Are the cells you want to "open" in column B? Please try the now changed code

Comment: Awesome, your last updated code works! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem, i am glad to be of service.