# Move Folder to Password Protected Sharepoint Server using VBS

Tags: sharepoint, vbscript, password-protection

I am trying to move a folder from a network location to a SharePoint site that I also have mapped as network folder using a vb script.  The SharePoint site prompts for active directory credentials upon opening the network folder.  I would also like to replace any existing folders on the SharePoint folder with the same name.  Here is what I have so far:

```
dim filesys
persistent = false
set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "S:", "\\<sharepoint site>", persistent, "username ", "password"


set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
filesys.MoveFolder "C:\Documents\TestFolder", "S:\New Folder\"
```

When I try to run this, I get an error message stating "the local device name has a remembered connection to another network resource."  Do I need to map the network connection each time the code is run?  Any assistance is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is as designed to drop idle connection to the server.

I use something similar as mentioned in this answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631401/access-network-share-from-within-vbscript-eg-filesystemobject)

Map the connection by mapping network drive, copy the files, drop the connection.