# VBScript access network share from domain

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to access and run setup.exe from a server on the same network.

- **The pc** where i'm trying to access the file from **is in a domain.**
- **The server is not in the domain.**

This code works **only if both pc's are without domain:**

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "M:", True, True

WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:", "\\192.168.0.10\share", myUserName, myPassword

Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
shell.CurrentDirectory = "M:\Setup"
shell.Run("setup.exe"), 0 , True

WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "M:", True, True
```

- If i try to run this code for my situation i get an error that username or password is wrong, but it isn't.
- If i manually map the drive and run the code then it works
- If i remove the map drive then the error is back.

**What extra details do i have to add so the pc can access the file from the server?**

Comment: If it is not in the domain then you need to have a local account setup on the server that matches your ID and PW,   Then when you login use the computers name WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:", "\\192.168.0.10\share", <PCName>\ID, PW

Comment: Until monday there is no way i can test this. I'll get back to you then.

Comment: I tried `WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:", "\\192.168.0.10\share", PC-10\administrator, password` and it throws error division by 0. If i try just with `administrator, password`, after 5 seconds it says wrong username or password. If i map the drive manually and run the script then it works. It must be something about the way i enter username and password i guess.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631401/access-network-share-from-within-vbscript-eg-filesystemobject) it says `UserName = "domain\username"` , but i can't use that because it's not the same situation. The server is not in the domain while the pc's are.