# VBScript map network drive (domain)

Tags: vbscript

**PC1** is where the script will run, and it **is in a domain.**
**PC2** holds the `share` folder and it's **NOT in any domain.**

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:", "\\192.168.0.10\share", administrator, password
```

**What else does the script needs to map the drive?**

---

Edit: This is sort of a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921116/vbscript-access-network-share-from-domain) , but i tried to simplify things.

Comment: So what happens? what is the format of the string in the variable `administrator`

Comment: The username and password for the shared folder are just strings. The PC name for the shared folder is like `PC-10` .  I tried `WshNetwork.MapNetwo‌​rkDrive "M:", "\\192.168.0.10\share‌​", PC-10\administrator, password` and it throws error division by 0. If i try just with administrator, password, after 5 seconds it says wrong username or password. If i map the drive manually and run the script then it works, but i can't do that for 100 pc's.

Comment: `administrator` is a variable right?  As it stands its not the word "administrator" unless you have assigned to it, same for your other attempt it should be `WshNetwork.MapNetwo‌​‌​rkDrive "M:", "\\192.168.0.10\share‌​‌​", "PC-10\administrator", "your_password"` - note the quotes

Comment: I just tried it `WshNetwork.MapNetwo‌​‌​‌​rkDrive "M:", "\\192.168.0.10\share‌​‌​‌​", "PC-10\administrator‌​", "password"` with the quotes and it's throwing error `Type missmatch`

Comment: Consult documentation for the MapNetworkDrive command. If you don't specify the `[persistent]` parameter, you still need to have a placeholder there. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Alex K. and @langstrom for pointing the right directions.

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:", "\\192.168.0.10\share", true, "BU-10\administrator", "password"
```