# Get Last Modified Time of a Shared Folder in Windows

Tags: vbscript

I need to check a shared Path for Subfolder\File existence. If it exists need to check whether the LastModified Time of the shared path has exceeded more than 1 hour.

I am getting error "Path not found" for shared path, but the code works fine for Normal Directory.

Here is my code

```
Dim fso, folder
folder = "C:/test"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folder)
If folder.Files.Count + folder.SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Folder is Empty"
ElseIf (folder.DateLastModified > 60) Then
    WScript.Echo "Exceeded 1 hour"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Not Exceeded 1 hour"
End If
```

This code works for the path mentioned in the script, but it throws error "Path not found" for the path `\\server.com\subfolder\subfolder\subfolder`.

Comment: Permissions probably do you run the script with elevated privileges?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat.aspx). Use the [`FolderExists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xc78d8d.aspx) method to verify the existence of folders. Use the [`FileExists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t.aspx) method to verify the existence of files.

Don't try to get a folder object unless you have verified it exists. Also, avoid re-using variables for different things.

```
path = "\\server\share\sub\folder"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FolderExists(path) Then
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)
    ...
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using a networked shared folder which requires user permissions to access, you should attempt to make a temporarily added network drive so vbscript can attempt to access it with credentials.

```
ServerShare = "\\192.168.3.56\d$"
UserName = "domain\username"
Password = "password"

Set NetworkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "", ServerShare, False, UserName, Password

Set Directory = FSO.GetFolder(ServerShare)
For Each FileName In Directory.Files
    WScript.Echo FileName.Name
Next

Set FileName = Nothing
Set Directory = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

NetworkObject.RemoveNetworkDrive ServerShare, True, False

Set ShellObject = Nothing
Set NetworkObject = Nothing
```

Stolen from here: [Access network share from within VBScript eg FileSystemObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631401/access-network-share-from-within-vbscript-eg-filesystemobject)